# Re-usable custom directive for modal window in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog

I have four menu bar tabs in my application. Each tab has settings icon where user can click on it and a modal window opens and user can perform delete/save/cancel operations on that Tab. For this, I want to create a re-usable modal window. This window will have unique information about each menu Tab. Can somebody help to create a custom directive-modal window when the user clicks on settings icon.

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about modal window then its bad idea..

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using bootstrap, I recommend using `ui.bootstrap.modal` from the [bootstrap angular directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for all your modal popup needs.

It's an easy way to handle everything related with modal windows. The actual content of the modal window may be in a separate template, or displayed using a custom directive which can be passed with the options to `$modal.open()`.